# Docker Run "executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Tags: docker, rust

I am a newbie trying to learn Docker. I am on WSL2 with Docker Desktop installed and running. I have a rust application that just runs a simple Actix web server. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.67

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY . .

RUN cargo install --path .

CMD ["myapp"]
```

Everything works up until the last CMD command, which gives this error when I run the container:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm --name my-running-app my-rust-app
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "myapp": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

I understand the error - the container can't find the rust executable for whatever reason.

I am out of ideas. Any help?

I have looked online for this issue and have tried the following:

- changing CMD to ENTRYPOINT
- running CMD ["./myapp"]
- adding the executable to PATH with an ENV command

Comment: The `CMD ["./myapp"]` suggests that you expect it to be installed in the current working directory, but that is not (necessarily) the case. Make sure you have the actual path to the  binary. Also, make sure to check out the docs for [cargo install](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-install.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a fix or not, but if it is relevant, I also have other binaries in the rust project (src/bin). I guess this makes a difference when running the cargo install command and not producing the executable. I changed the last line of the Dockerfile to `CMD ["./target/release/<name>"]`, where <name> is the name of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing the full path of the executable. You can get it by running `cargo install --path . --list` in your local Rust project directory.
The output would be something like `/usr/local/cargo/bin/myapp`.
Update the CMD instruction like `CMD ["/usr/local/cargo/bin/myapp"]`.
Rebuild the image and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same NAME:

"*Your project name*" = CMD ["*Your project name*"]

- if your project named "myapp", then type `CMD ["myapp"]`.
- if your project named "api-server", then type `CMD ["api-server"]`.

Because cargo build or install project, one result is executable-program and named "*Your project name*".

If name is different, docker can't find it by name, then throws
"executable file not found in $PATH: unknown".